# Ionic read local photo and display

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to display a photo from my photo gallery.

I am using, in my case, this html code to show the image

```
<img style="border:1px solid red;width:100%;height:400px;"
                     src="file:///storage/9016-4EF8/DCIM/Camera/20160723_134932.jpg" />
```

So, the image is not showing.

Also, I verified and the URL is valid. I have used the following code to make sure that I can read the file:

```
        File.readAsText("file:///storage/9016-4EF8/DCIM/Camera/", "20160723_134932.jpg")
            .then((obj) => {
                console.log('I CAN READ THE FILE');
            })
            .catch((obj) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
            });
```

There are other things that I have done:

Changed the meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * cdvfile://*; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Modified the Config.xml

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-intent href="file:///*"/>
<allow-navigation href="*://*/*"/>
```

But still not working, the image is not displayed.

I have lost three days trying to do it work.

Answer (score 0):

I can not believe I did find the solution.

If you are running the Ionic with --livereload, the image will not show.

Unintentionally I run the project with the command:

```
ionic run --device
```

Without "--livereload". I did it to complete my question and voilà, it works.

OMG!!!!!

So, I will mantain this question for further searches and to help someone.

Now I can sleep, lol.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by using the method `readAsDataURL` in the cordova file plugin (cordova-plugin-file). No need to change the CSP or the config.xml. Only tested with android device and emulator (with --livereload)).

```
this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageUri) => {
  const indexOfLastSlash = imageUri.lastIndexOf('/');
  const path = imageUri.substring(0, indexOfLastSlash);
  const filename = imageUri.substring(indexOfLastSlash + 1);
  this.file.readAsDataURL(path, filename).then((imageDataUrl) => {
    this.imageDataUrl = imageDataUrl;
  })
}, (err) => {
});
```

This is only a workaround and should not be used in production as every image will be loaded into memory.